# Line indentor - Trying to pass the length of javaline in each line between classes however it keeps being set to 0

Tags: java

I have the task of making an indentor for some javaline. The idea is that first I have to split the java from the comment.  I then have to find the longest line of just javacode excluding the comment from the input file and use that for the max length of java. However I have run into the issue of that its returning with 0 every time and not the longest line in an array.

The first piece of code is the class that holds the method for working out the longest length of javaline. The method is called findMaxJavaLineLength():

```
import java.util.*;

class Program
{

    private ArrayList<JavaLine> stored = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public Program()
    {
        stored.clear();
    }

    /**
     * Add the next line of Java code to the stored program
     * @param line A line of Java code
     */
    public void addLine( String line )
    {
        stored.add( new JavaLine( line) );
    }

    public String indentProgram()
    {
        String res = "";

        for ( JavaLine line: stored )
        {
            res += line.returnLineWithCommentAt() + "\n";
        }
        return res;

    }

    public int findMaxJavaLineLength()
    {
        int max = 0;

        for ( JavaLine line: stored )
        {
            int lineLength = line.getJavaLineLength();
            if ( lineLength > max) max = lineLength;
        }
        return max;
    }

}
```

and the second piece of code is the JavaLine class which splits the code into parts and returns the length of java:

```
class JavaLine
{
    private String java    = ""; // Java code on line 
    private String comment = ""; // The single line comment
    private String javaSpace = "";
    private int lenJava = 0;  // The line length of just the java cod

    public JavaLine( String line )
    {
        String[] splitted = line.split("// ");
        java = splitted[0];
        int slashCount = line.length() - line.replaceAll("//","").length();
        if (slashCount >= 1) {
            comment = "// " + splitted[1];
        }

    }

    public int getJavaLineLength()
    {

        lenJava = java.length();
        return lenJava;

    }

    public String returnLineWithCommentAt( )
    {
        String output = "";
        Program t = new Program();
        int maxLenJavaLine = t.findMaxJavaLineLength();
        int number = maxLenJavaLine - getJavaLineLength();
        String javaSpace = "";

        for (int n = 0; n < number; n++){
            javaSpace = javaSpace + " ";
        }

        String commentOutput = comment;
        if ( java.contains("}")){
            output = java;
        }else if ( java.contains("{")){
            output = java;
        } else {
            output = java + javaSpace + commentOutput + "test: " + t.findMaxJavaLineLength();
        }

        return output;

    }
}
```

I have tested it and it seems like the lenJava bit in the getjavalength is working out the length of the javaline correctly when I grab it from the same class. However it sets to 0 when I grab it from the other class when trying to work out the longest line. It seems as if the length just doesn't get passed to the other class from the javaline class.

Below is the output that I am currently receiving.

```
import java.lang.Thread;// Use External classtest: 0
class Countdowntest: 0
{
 public static void main( String args[] )test: 0
 {
 // Start from 10test: 0
 while ( countdown > 0 )// While greater than 0test: 0
 {
 System.out.println(countdown);// Write contents of countdowntest: 0
 if ( countdown == 3 )// If equal to 3test: 0
 {
 System.out.println("Ignition");// Write Ignitiontest: 0
 }
 countdown--;// Decrement countdown by 1test: 0
 try {
 Thread.sleep( 100 );// 1000 milliseconds delaytest: 0
 }
 catch( InterruptedException e ) {}
 }
 System.out.println( "Blast Off");// Write Blast offtest: 0
 }
}
```

The bit of the output where it says "test: 0" is where I am expecting the length of the javaline which is the longest. so it should be "test: 50" or whatever instead of "test: 0".

Thank you

Comment: What does 'length of java' mean? What is your question?

Comment: Length of java is the length of the code in the output without the comment included. At the minute the length of the java is not being passed from JavaLine within the getJavaLineLength() method. For instance in the output bit if I add "lenJava" to the output the length of the javacode at the start of the line is added however lenJava is not being passed to Program class so it is unable to calculate the longest string out of the input file.

Comment: Do you mean the length of one line of Java code? Make yourself clear.

Comment: Sorry my bad, Yeah - length of one line of java code.

Comment: So fix your question and your title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a new `Program` called `t` in the second line of `JavaLine.returnLineWithCommentAt()` but you don't add any lines to it with `addLine()` before calling `findMaxJavaLineLength()` on it, so of course it contains no lines and `findMaxJavaLineLength()` returns 0.

Perhaps you intended to call `findMaxJavaLineLength()` from `Program.indentProgram()` and then pass that value into `returnLineWithCommentAt()`?

Just change the signature of `returnLineWithCommentAt()` to

```
public String returnLineWithCommentAt(int maxLineLength)
```

And then you can call it in `Program.indentProgram()` thus:

```
int maxLineLength = findMaxJavaLineLength();
for (JavaLine line: stored)
{
    res += line.returnLineWithCommentAt(maxLineLength) + "\n";
}
```

Don't forget to remove `t` from `JavaLine.returnLineWithCommentAt()`.

Comment: How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: I do intend to pass an already filled program into it however I am not sure how I would do so without setting the method as static?

Comment: On second thoughts, what you want to do I think is to call `findMaxJavaLineLength()` from `Program.indentProgram()` and then pass that value into `returnLineWithCommentAt()`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! Works perfectly